# Bake Animation Nodes text animation

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

Is it possible to bake an Animation Nodes animation that uses Trim Text and Text Object Output nodes?

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwdBy21XQbk) to create a typewriter text animation effect.

[image]

I eventually want to remove the node tree but keep the animation and have seen that Animation Nodes has a Bake to Keyframes option.

[image]

However, when I press this nothing happens. If I remove the node tree the text remains static. Is there any way to bake this animation? I have also tried exporting the file to an Alembic file but the output is only a few hundred bytes in size and doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Blender does not allow key-framing text data, so you can't really bake this animation to key-frames. What you can do is separate the texts using the *Separate Text* node and then animate the scale or the visibility of the individual characters as follows:

[image: Node Tree]